# handling application closing in mobile devices phonegap jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova

Working on a mobile application using jquery mobile and phonegap framework. My question is rather basic - How would you tap into application closing events. Scenario - When a user clicks the close app button if the application is in the middle of some processing I would like to do some cleanup - example write some status codes to a file. My app cannot do a clean exit. Is there an event for app closing that we could tap into either in phonegap or jquery?

I could see references on how to exit an app but nothing on tapping an event fired when someone closes an app.

Currently working on a blackberry application using phonegap/jquery mobile.

**EDIT**

For the blackberry we could use

```
blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK, 
function() { 
             alert('back button pressed');               
         });
```

However, I am not sure if what to use to close the app after handling the event consistently on all Blackberry phones.

```
navigator.app.exitApp() or 
device.exitApp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See phonegap api -> events -> pause:

```
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause
```

Comment: Would the pause event be fired when the app is quit - example - by pressing the escape key on blackberry? I was under the impression that it would only be fired when the app is relegated to the background.

Comment: I don't know much about black berry but there is also events for `menubutton`, `endcallbutton`, etc.